# How do I make a JavaScript automatic background slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my background image to be an automatic slider of 4 seconds for each slide and the slider should auto stop after the last slide.

I have 2 slides in total(slide_1.png & slide_2.png).

So basically what I am trying to achieve here is a google ads banner of size 300x600 which should not be above 150kb in a zipped folder folder

I want my banner to have a real-time clock and two images as background slides

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>300x600</title>
    <meta name="ad.size" content="width=300, height=600">
</head>



<body>


<style>
body, html {
    height: 600px;
    width: 300px;
    background-image: url('slide_2.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center
    left:100%;
    top:100%;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-top:0px
  



</style>



<canvas id="canvas" width="226" height="226"
style="position: absolute;
    left: 41px;
    top: 321px;" >
</canvas>



<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = canvas.height / 2;
ctx.translate(radius, radius);
radius = radius * 0.50
setInterval(drawClock, 1000);

function drawClock() {
  drawFace(ctx, radius);
  drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
  drawTime(ctx, radius);
}

function drawFace(ctx, radius) {
  var grad;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fill();
  grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0,0,radius*0.95, 0,0,radius*1.05);
  grad.addColorStop(0, '#333');
  grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'white');
  grad.addColorStop(1, '#333');
  ctx.strokeStyle = grad;
  ctx.lineWidth = radius*0.1;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius*0.1, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
  var ang;
  var num;
  ctx.font = radius*0.15 + "px arial";
  ctx.textBaseline="middle";
  ctx.textAlign="center";
  for(num = 1; num < 13; num++){
    ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, -radius*0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
    ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, radius*0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
  }
}

function drawTime(ctx, radius){
    var now = new Date();
    var hour = now.getHours();
    var minute = now.getMinutes();
    var second = now.getSeconds();
    //hour
    hour=hour%12;
    hour=(hour*Math.PI/6)+
    (minute*Math.PI/(6*60))+
    (second*Math.PI/(360*60));
    drawHand(ctx, hour, radius*0.5, radius*0.07);
    //minute
    minute=(minute*Math.PI/30)+(second*Math.PI/(30*60));
    drawHand(ctx, minute, radius*0.8, radius*0.07);
    // second
    second=(second*Math.PI/30);
    drawHand(ctx, second, radius*0.9, radius*0.02);
}

function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = width;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.rotate(pos);
    ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.rotate(-pos);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds good, what problem are you having?

Comment: at this time the background image is static i want it to be an animated slideshow with a total of two slides each that will last for 4 seconds then stop at the last slide

Comment: what kind of animation do you need?

Comment: Fade out animation for the first slide after 4 seconds and the and the last slide should remain.  in javascript

Comment: why not just use a div, and animate the background property ?

Comment: how do i go about it? i have tried but the div covered my clock and only the image was visible

Comment: look into CSS [animations](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp)

Comment: If somthing is overlaping then try to play with `z-index` https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>300x600</title>
    <meta name="ad.size" content="width=300, height=600">
</head>



<body>


<style>
body, html {
    height: 600px;
    width: 300px;
    background-image: url('slide_2.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center
    left:100%;
    top:100%;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-top:0px
  



</style>



<canvas id="canvas" width="226" height="226"
style="position: absolute;
    left: 41px;
    top: 321px;" >
</canvas>



<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = canvas.height / 2;
var slideNumber = 4; // total number of slides
var slideIndex = 0; //index of current slide
var interval = setInterval(changeBackground, 4000);

ctx.translate(radius, radius);
radius = radius * 0.50
setInterval(drawClock, 1000);

    function changeBackground() {
        slideIndex += 1;
        if(slideIndex > slideNumber){
             clearInterval(interval);
             return;
        }
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://picsum.photos/200/300/?image=" + slideIndex + "')"; 
        console.log(slideIndex);
    }

function drawClock() {
  drawFace(ctx, radius);
  drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
  drawTime(ctx, radius);
}

function drawFace(ctx, radius) {
  var grad;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fill();
  grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0,0,radius*0.95, 0,0,radius*1.05);
  grad.addColorStop(0, '#333');
  grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'white');
  grad.addColorStop(1, '#333');
  ctx.strokeStyle = grad;
  ctx.lineWidth = radius*0.1;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius*0.1, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
  var ang;
  var num;
  ctx.font = radius*0.15 + "px arial";
  ctx.textBaseline="middle";
  ctx.textAlign="center";
  for(num = 1; num < 13; num++){
    ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, -radius*0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
    ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, radius*0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
  }
}

function drawTime(ctx, radius){
    var now = new Date();
    var hour = now.getHours();
    var minute = now.getMinutes();
    var second = now.getSeconds();
    //hour
    hour=hour%12;
    hour=(hour*Math.PI/6)+
    (minute*Math.PI/(6*60))+
    (second*Math.PI/(360*60));
    drawHand(ctx, hour, radius*0.5, radius*0.07);
    //minute
    minute=(minute*Math.PI/30)+(second*Math.PI/(30*60));
    drawHand(ctx, minute, radius*0.8, radius*0.07);
    // second
    second=(second*Math.PI/30);
    drawHand(ctx, second, radius*0.9, radius*0.02);
}

function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = width;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.rotate(pos);
    ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.rotate(-pos);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i'm a bit lost, already that the second image isn't declared in the code

Comment: @TchemedjeRhonnelYvan see if this helps.

Comment: i have added the code to the script but there's no change

Comment: @TchemedjeRhonnelYvan it works fine for me, though i've made a slight change but i'm sure it works.

Comment: @TchemedjeRhonnelYvan there you go.

Comment: i dont understand how yours work i have changed my code then replaced the image but it doesn't still work

Comment: say you have a series of image named slide_n.png where n is a number. this code loops through the sequence of images by replacing n with a number, you should change "url('https://picsum.photos/200/300/?image=" + slideIndex + "')" to  "url('slide_" + slideIndex + ".png')"

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS animation and pseudo elements.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>300x600</title>
  <meta name="ad.size" content="width=300, height=600">
</head>



<body>


  <style>
    body,
    html {
      height: 600px;
      width: 300px;
      top: 100%;
      margin-left: 0px;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
    
    body:before,
    body:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center left:100%;
    }
    
    body:before {
      background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/300/600?image=100');
      animation: fadeOut 1s linear 2s 1 forwards;
      -webkit-animation: fadeOut 1s linear 2s 1 forwards;
      -moz-animation: fadeOut 1s linear 2s 1 forwards;
      -o-animation: fadeOut 1s linear 2s 1 forwards;
    }
    
    body:after {
      background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/300/600?image=201');
      z-index: -1;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
      from {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      to {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes fadeOut {
      from {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      to {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
  </style>



  <canvas id="canvas" width="226" height="226" style="position: absolute;
    left: 41px;
    top: 0;">
</canvas>



  <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var radius = canvas.height / 2;
    ctx.translate(radius, radius);
    radius = radius * 0.50
    setInterval(drawClock, 1000);

    function drawClock() {
      drawFace(ctx, radius);
      drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
      drawTime(ctx, radius);
    }

    function drawFace(ctx, radius) {
      var grad;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
      ctx.fill();
      grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0, 0, radius * 0.95, 0, 0, radius * 1.05);
      grad.addColorStop(0, '#333');
      grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'white');
      grad.addColorStop(1, '#333');
      ctx.strokeStyle = grad;
      ctx.lineWidth = radius * 0.1;
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(0, 0, radius * 0.1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
      ctx.fill();
    }

    function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
      var ang;
      var num;
      ctx.font = radius * 0.15 + "px arial";
      ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
      ctx.textAlign = "center";
      for (num = 1; num < 13; num++) {
        ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
        ctx.rotate(ang);
        ctx.translate(0, -radius * 0.85);
        ctx.rotate(-ang);
        ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
        ctx.rotate(ang);
        ctx.translate(0, radius * 0.85);
        ctx.rotate(-ang);
      }
    }

    function drawTime(ctx, radius) {
      var now = new Date();
      var hour = now.getHours();
      var minute = now.getMinutes();
      var second = now.getSeconds();
      //hour
      hour = hour % 12;
      hour = (hour * Math.PI / 6) +
        (minute * Math.PI / (6 * 60)) +
        (second * Math.PI / (360 * 60));
      drawHand(ctx, hour, radius * 0.5, radius * 0.07);
      //minute
      minute = (minute * Math.PI / 30) + (second * Math.PI / (30 * 60));
      drawHand(ctx, minute, radius * 0.8, radius * 0.07);
      // second
      second = (second * Math.PI / 30);
      drawHand(ctx, second, radius * 0.9, radius * 0.02);
    }

    function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.lineWidth = width;
      ctx.lineCap = "round";
      ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
      ctx.rotate(pos);
      ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.rotate(-pos);
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the background image doesn't change

Comment: @TchemedjeRhonnelYvan yes it is

Comment: do i have merged the code to one file, I put my two images in the placeholders  but it doesn't

Comment: can you maybe make it one file?

Comment: @TchemedjeRhonnelYvan of course. Place that css code into your `style` tag. I updated the snippet

Comment: It does work, only that the first slide stays for only about 2 seconds

Comment: @TchemedjeRhonnelYvan yes i set delay to 2 seconds for now. And what happens after?

Comment: This snippet above is working properly for you on this site. Right?

Comment: Two pseudo elements of body `:before`&`:after` act as canvas for image here. First element goes transparent after delay. That's all it does...

Look at console or network tab in developer tools of your browser. Maybe image is not loading.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>300x600</title>
  <meta name="ad.size" content="width=300, height=600">
</head>



<body>


  <style>
    body,
    html {
      height: 600px;
      width: 300px;
      top: 100%;
      margin-left: 0px;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
    
    body:before,
    body:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center left:100%;
    }
    
    body:before {
      background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/300/600?image=100');
      animation: fadeOut 1s linear 2s 1 forwards;
      -webkit-animation: fadeOut 1s linear 2s 1 forwards;
      -moz-animation: fadeOut 1s linear 2s 1 forwards;
      -o-animation: fadeOut 1s linear 2s 1 forwards;
    }
    
    body:after {
      background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/300/600?image=201');
      z-index: -1;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
      from {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      to {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes fadeOut {
      from {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      to {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
  </style>



  <canvas id="canvas" width="226" height="226" style="position: absolute;
    left: 41px;
    top: 0;">
</canvas>



  <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var radius = canvas.height / 2;
    ctx.translate(radius, radius);
    radius = radius * 0.50
    setInterval(drawClock, 1000);

    function drawClock() {
      drawFace(ctx, radius);
      drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
      drawTime(ctx, radius);
    }

    function drawFace(ctx, radius) {
      var grad;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
      ctx.fill();
      grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0, 0, radius * 0.95, 0, 0, radius * 1.05);
      grad.addColorStop(0, '#333');
      grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'white');
      grad.addColorStop(1, '#333');
      ctx.strokeStyle = grad;
      ctx.lineWidth = radius * 0.1;
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(0, 0, radius * 0.1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
      ctx.fill();
    }

    function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
      var ang;
      var num;
      ctx.font = radius * 0.15 + "px arial";
      ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
      ctx.textAlign = "center";
      for (num = 1; num < 13; num++) {
        ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
        ctx.rotate(ang);
        ctx.translate(0, -radius * 0.85);
        ctx.rotate(-ang);
        ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
        ctx.rotate(ang);
        ctx.translate(0, radius * 0.85);
        ctx.rotate(-ang);
      }
    }

    function drawTime(ctx, radius) {
      var now = new Date();
      var hour = now.getHours();
      var minute = now.getMinutes();
      var second = now.getSeconds();
      //hour
      hour = hour % 12;
      hour = (hour * Math.PI / 6) +
        (minute * Math.PI / (6 * 60)) +
        (second * Math.PI / (360 * 60));
      drawHand(ctx, hour, radius * 0.5, radius * 0.07);
      //minute
      minute = (minute * Math.PI / 30) + (second * Math.PI / (30 * 60));
      drawHand(ctx, minute, radius * 0.8, radius * 0.07);
      // second
      second = (second * Math.PI / 30);
      drawHand(ctx, second, radius * 0.9, radius * 0.02);
    }

    function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.lineWidth = width;
      ctx.lineCap = "round";
      ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
      ctx.rotate(pos);
      ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.rotate(-pos);
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```